# Angular2 RequestOptionsArgs not accepted in ASP.NET Core 2.1 REST API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am struggling with Angular2 and ASP.NET Core 2.1 application.

Creating Excel file with EPPlus.Core corrupts file after downloading it in Angular client side.

Problem is now that if I add `http.post` `RequestOptionsArgs` part then API is not called. How to get API called if `RequestOptionsArgs` are included?
I saw that `RequestOptionsArgs` is deprecated in later Angular versions.

```
 getSearchedReportsToExcel(filterObject: FilterObject){
 this._http.post(AppSettings.GetSearchedReportsToExcelUrl, filterObject, 
   {
     method: RequestMethod.Post,
     responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
     headers: new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
   }).subscribe(
       response => { // download file
         var blob = new Blob([response.blob()],
           {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
         var filename = 'file.xlsx';
         saveAs(blob, filename);
      },
      error => {
             console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      }
   );
 }
```

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")]
public IActionResult GetSearchedReportsToExcel([FromBody]FilterObjectDTO filterObject)
{
...
}
```

I created `HttpGet` API function and decorated it with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. I think that there should be better solution. Without attribute 401 error is returned.
[Unauthorizes response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDG4N.png)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I am getting unauthorized response 401. If I add [AllowAnonymous] attribute then it works.

Comment: you need to add your authorization data to your request headers. Probably that is some kind of token, I don't know what are you using